# Group a Table by 2 columns and give priority to not null value?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have only access to the DB and could not change how the results are being stored.

I have a table like this where we have

```
UserID, Gender, Category

'f2', NULL,  '2'
'f2', 'female',  '2'
'05', 'male',  '2'
'06', 'female',  '2'
'ee', 'female',  '2'
'bd', NULL,  '2'
'dd', NULL,  '2'
'01', NULL,  '2'
```

This is the query which I'm using now

```
SELECT 
    gender,
    count(*) count
FROM
    user_history
WHERE
    1
    AND GROUP BY UserID, Gender,Category
```

This gives me wrong result cause it is merging without giving priority to the Gender Column (f2 with the gender is removed)

And How can I get a result similar to this? Expected output:

gender count

```
female  3     (f2,06,ee)
male    1     (only 05 is there)
unknown 3     (f2 has duplicate entries and one of the row has a gender, so I've to give priority to that)
```

Comment: you need count for genders?

Comment: Yes, and I need the count of null genders (unknown) too

Comment: what is your current and expected output? can you describe clearly.

Comment: 'And How can I get a result similar to this?' Below that line I've added the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with 2 levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Gender, 'Unknown') Gender, 
       COUNT(*) counter
FROM (
  SELECT UserID, MAX(Gender) Gender
  FROM user_history
  GROUP BY UserID
) t
GROUP BY Gender
```

or if you also want to group by `Category`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Gender, 'Unknown') Gender, 
       COUNT(*) counter,
       Category
FROM (
  SELECT UserID, MAX(Gender) Gender, Category
  FROM user_history
  GROUP BY UserID, Category
) t
GROUP BY Gender, Category
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1133c3713ef39ff44ed75df3615d0379).